# How to change resizing areas of a custom shaped NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

In my macOS app, I created a custom shaped window which visible frame is less than actual. I want to make invisible areas inactive for user interactions. I've played with `NSWindow`'s `frameRect(forContentRect contentRect: NSRect)` and other methods, tracking areas of it's `contentView` but achieve no success. Is it possible or I'm just wasting time?

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a partially transparent window to allow content to extend beyond it, you could try using a more normal window with an attached child window for the out-of-bounds content.

Comment: @KenThomases Yeah, that’s exactly what I did after wasting a few more hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## the main thing to do

Making a custom window starts with a transparent window.
=> that makes OSX pass through clicks on non-opaque areas of the window

In your window subclass you gotta override init and set opaque to NO

## further read

I could reiterate all from the old bbut good cocoawithlove tutorial bbut instead, ill link it:
https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: I've read this tutorial. The window is opaque already. Here is subclass setup code

```titleVisibility = .hidden
  styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
  titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
  isOpaque = false
  backgroundColor = .clear
  
  let toolbar = NSToolbar()
  toolbar.showsBaselineSeparator = false
  self.toolbar = toolbar```

Comment: @Akki – Daij-Djan is correct, if the window is non-opaque clicks should pass through transparent parts. You can then catch any clicks and do whatever resize/drag operations you want. If your window is non-opaque already and yet clicks in transparent parts are getting caught you will need to edit your question and add your code to enable people to help you.